# How to use Library in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-library

I want to use this [viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#usage) for my current project but fail at importing the library. Could someone explain in steps how to use this library? When i download it, it is an ZIP file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to look inside the zip?

So I assume you are using Android studio with the gradle build system. You can import the library as a module inside your project and than import it like this

```
compile project(':library')
```

Or you can create a build.gradle inside the library project and use an upload task http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html to upload an aar on a nexus server or to your local maven repo http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html and than import it in your project `compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:version'`

Comment: Funny that this answer that doesn't use IntelliJ but Android Studio and Gradle is marked as accepted...